# Obfuscator-LLVM + xcode clang 3.4: "unknown argument"

Tags: xcode, clang, llvm, obfuscation, llvm-clang

I'm having a real hard time using [Obfuscator-LLVM](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator) in Xcode.. I don't understand why, after creating the plugin for it and selecting it in my build settings, I can't compile because clang is giving this "unknown arguments" errors.

```
clang-3.4: error: unknown argument: '-gmodules' 
clang-3.4: error: unknown argument: '-fbuild-session-file=/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation' 
clang-3.4: error: unknown argument: '-fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session' Command /Users/user/Thesis/llvm_obfuscator/obfuscator/build/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

any possible solution? What am I doing wrong???

I'm using Xcode 7.3,
llvm 3.4

I already tried adding -Qunused-arguments in CFlags and CPPFlags in Xcode.

[Edit]:
I just noticed that if I disable the Modules option in the [Obfuscator-LLVM](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator) 3.4 for C and C++ it compiles... still I need to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean [Obfuscator-LLVM](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator), it hasn't been updated with support for Xcode 7 (as of April 2016), and module support is broken. They haven't merged in [Apple's latest (open-source) LLVM changes](http://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-700.0.72/).

Comment: I'll try downgrading my Xcode version. One last question: maybe you could suggest me which version to downgrade it to.

Thanks a lot for the answer.